# Remote plugin update but skip certain files

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

### What

Our company uses an internal WordPress plugin that contains custom post types, taxonomies, helper functions, and misc. extensions on client websites. What I would like to do is set up remote updates for this plugin targeting the misc. extensions folder but leaving the other files alone.

### Why

Most of the files in the plugin are specific to the client website, including custom post types, taxonomies, and helper functions. With recent WordPress updates, we have found the need to update some of the extensions, and rather than connecting to each client site individually, it would be ideal to push these and future updates remotely.

### Thought Process

Since WordPress automatically deletes the plugin's directory, these files will be lost. I have found [this old tutorial](https://www.hungred.com/how-to/prevent-wordpress-plugin-update-deleting-important-folder-plugin/) that suggests moving files/directories to the parent directory temporarily using 'upgrader_pre_install' and then pulling in those files after the plugin has been updated, but it feels dirty. Are there any other ways to do this?